# how to check if the enter key is pressed python

Tags: python, tkinter, key, enter

I have a bind event for when a key is pressed to trigger a function but how would I see if the key pressed was the enter key?
Here is my code:

This did not work. What would I replace the word enter with to check if the enter key is pressed:

```
def record(self,event):
    x = event.char
    if x == "Enter":
        print("Enter")
```

Comment: Can you add the bind for this event? - your problem may lie there.

Comment: @Shadow9043 self.bind_all("<Key>", self.record)

Comment: @cdw100100 is this tkinter? Please tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check using keysym:

```
if event.keysym == 'Return'
```